# JavaScript alert on window.unload when browser is closed but should not alert when browser is refreshed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to popup a message in `window.onunload` event.

Currently when user:

a) navigates away
b) closes the window
c) presses <kbd>F5</kbd> or
d) presses refresh button in browser tool bar

The alert will appear., but I need it to not alert when user clicks the browser tool bar refresh button.

We added conditions for not alerting when users presses <kbd>F5</kbd> or navigates away but alert should also not appear when users clicks browser refresh button.

Any type of workarounds would be nice.

Comment: Well as far as I know, this is not possible. Though if you share the reason why you need it, the same could be fulfilled with a better solution.

Comment: Ahem? 2 and 3 do not make sense. Alert when the user press the refresh button in the browser toolbar but do NOT alert when the user clicks the browser tool bar refresh button... ???

Comment: ^Well all that he means is he wants the alert to come up in all unload cases apart from click on the refresh button. Language is confusing though.

Comment: I have edited your question - let me know if I worded it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a way to know if the user clicked on a browser button (back, forward, closing browser, etc...). I couldn't find any way to figure out which button was clicked,
But I hope it will help you.

To know if the user clicked on a browser button, follow these steps:
1. Register window.beforeunload event.
2. In the handler, check event.clientY.
3. If event.clientY is not defiend or event.clientY<0, then you know the user clicked a browser button.

For example: 
(You probably will have to change the code to fit it to your problem)

```
function beforeUnloadHandler(eventArg)
{
   var _e = window.event || eventArg;

   // browser button click
   if (isNaN(_e.clientY) || _e.clientY < 0) 
   {
       // unload process will continue
       // and unload event will be fired
       return;
   }

   // a confirmation with 'test alert' text will appear
   // if the user clicks 'Cancel', the unload process will stop 
   // and unload event won't be fired.
   return "test alert";
}
window.onbeforeunload = beforeUnloadHandler;
```

This code will work in all major browsers: chrome, ff, ie9,ie8,ie7,ie6, opera 11, opera 10, safari 3,4,5.